# IMO problem about regular polygons whose vertices lie on equidistant parallel lines

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Infinitely many equidistant parallel lines are draw in the plane. A positive integer $n \geq 3$ is called *frameable* if it  is possible to draw a  regular polygon with $n$ sides all whose vertices lie on these lines, and no line contains more than one vertex of the polygon.
(a) Show that $3, 4, 6$ are frameable
(b) Show that any integer $n > 6$ is not frameable
(c) Determine whether $5$ is frameable

So I have been trying this question that came in Indian National Math Olympiad this year. I have proved it for $n=6$ but unable to show that it is not possible for $n>6$.

For n = 6, the lines have to inclined like this. I have also found the angle associated with it.

[Check the image for n=6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEI17.png)

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Posted the complete question. Help me out with the relevant tag?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you did for the case $n = 6$.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: This is from Inmo 2020 name of the proposer was Muralidharan.Please Check on Aops for solution.(If there is any it will surely help you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed complex numbers in INMO then you can proceed as follows.

For $n>6$, let $w$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity chosen so that  $|w-1|<1$.

Let the sides of the regular $n$-gon be $a,wa,w^2a,...,w^{n-1}a$, where $w$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity. Then these complex numbers represent displacements between points on the parallel lines. Therefore any integer combination of these numbers, such as $(w-1)^ka$, represents such a displacement.

However, by choosing a suitably large $k$ we can make $(w-1)^ka$ as small in magnitude as we like. All such numbers cannot therefore be displacements between points on the parallel lines unless $a$ is parallel to the lines. This is a contradiction since no line contains two points of the $n$-gon.

Comment: I apologize if this is stupid, but why can you consider $(w-1)^ka$ as a displacement? Where does the exponent $k$ come from? Moreover, I don't get where you are using the hypothesis that any two consecutive parallels lines are at the same distance (which is clearly a necessary condition for the exercise).

Comment: Re the lines, we can add the displacements so freely precisely because it does not matter where the initial point is on **any** line because all the distances are the same.

Comment: Re. them being displacements, each of $a,wa, $etc are clearly displacements. But then such expressions as $5a-17wa+9w^2a...$ are also displacements. $(w-1)^ka$ is just one such displacement for any $k$.

Comment: P.S. You might find it helpful to try this with your hexagon. You'll see that the only difference from the above answer is that $|w-1|=1$ and so you don't get a contradiction by this process.